# Doing subqueries in Mybatis, or query recursively the selected values

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

UPDATE:

I understood that the solution to my problem is doing subqueries, which apply a different filter each time, and they have a reduced result set. But I can't find a way to do that in MyBatis logic. Here is my query code

```
List<IstanzaMetadato> res = null;

    SqlSession sqlSession = ConnectionFactory.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(true);
    try {
        IstanzaMetadatoMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(IstanzaMetadatoMapper.class);
        IstanzaMetadatoExample example = new IstanzaMetadatoExample();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();               
            example.createCriteria().andIdMetadatoEqualTo(entry.getKey()).andValoreEqualTo(entry.getValue());
        }

        example.setDistinct(true);

        res = mapper.selectByExample(example);
```

I need to execute a new selectByExample but inside the while cycle, and it has to query the previus "SELECTED" results....

Is there a Solution ?

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have this table structure

[image]

I have to select rows from the table with different filters, specified by the final user.
Those filters are specified by a couple (id_metadato, valore), in example you can have id_metadato = 3 and valore = "pippo";

the user can specify 0-n filters from the web page typing 0-n values inside the search boxes which are based on id_metadato

Obviusly, the more filters the users specifies, the more restriction would have the final query.

In example if the user fills only the first search box, the query will have only a filter and would provide all the rows that will have the couple (id_metadato, valore) specified by the user. 
If he uses two search boxes, than the query will have 2 filters, and it will provide all the rows that verify the first condition AND the second one, after the "first subquery" is done.

I need to do this dinamically, and in the best efficient way. I can't simply add AND clause to my query, they have to filter and reduce the result set every time.
I can't do 0-n subqueries (Select * from ... IN (select * from ....) ) efficiently.

Is there a more elegant way to do that ? I'm reading dynamic SQL queries tutorials with MyBatis, but I'm not sure that is the correct way. I'm still trying to figure out the logic of the resosultio, then I will try to implement with MyBatis.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyBatis simplified a lot this process of nesting subqueries, it was sufficient to concatenate the filter criterias and to add

the excerpt of the code is the following

```
try {
        IstanzaMetadatoMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(IstanzaMetadatoMapper.class);
        IstanzaMetadatoExample example = new IstanzaMetadatoExample();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();
            if (listaIdUd.isEmpty()) {
                example.createCriteria().andIdMetadatoEqualTo(entry.getKey()).andValoreEqualTo(entry.getValue());
                example.setDistinct(true);
                listaIdUd = mapper.selectDynamicNested(example);
                continue;
            }
            example.clear();
            example.createCriteria().andIdMetadatoEqualTo(entry.getKey()).andValoreEqualTo(entry.getValue()).andIdUdIn(listaIdUd);
            example.setDistinct(true);
            listaIdUd = mapper.selectDynamicNested(example);
        }
```